# Multiple files read and process in R

Tags: r, loops

I have a huge data set of XLSX files: *Data_203001*, *Data_203002*, ...

I did some analysis on them (single file used each time) that I would like implement on the full set one by one and then save it with *Results_203001*, *Results_203001*, ...

So, I guess I'm looking for some guidance how to assign variable in to the path name and then save results with the same variable assign to the results name and do it in loop for the whole set.

Thank you for any help, I'm quite now to R so I appreciate any help.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions . I will try and see what works for me. Appreciate help I was given.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would do the trick:

```
# list all xslx data
all_files <- list.files(path = "path_to_data", 
                        pattern = "Data_\\d+\\.xlsx$", 
                        full.names = TRUE)
# process each file:
lapply(X = all_files,
       FUN = function(path) {
  # read your data
  df <- openxlsx::read.xlsx(path)
  # do your transformation
  df_out <- some_transformations_to_your_data(df)

  # replace data with result to get new filename:
  path_out <- sub(pattern = "Data", replacement = "Results", x = path_out)

  # write result to new filename:
  openxlsx::write.xlsx(x = df_out, file = path_out)
})
```

### Edit:

In case you need more output as stated in comments, do something like this:

```
for (transformation_type in c("epi", "miss", "algor")) {
  openxlsx::write.xlsx(
    x = do.call(what = paste0("transformation_", transformation_type), args = list(df = df)), 
    file = sub(pattern = "Data", replacement = paste0(transformation_type, "_Results"), x = path_out)
  )
}
```

Such that the whole expression becomes:

```
# list all xslx data
all_files <- list.files(path = "path_to_data", 
                        pattern = "Data_\\d+\\.xlsx$", 
                        full.names = TRUE)
# process each file:
lapply(X = all_files,
       FUN = function(path) {
         # read your data
         df <- openxlsx::read.xlsx(path)
         # do your transformation
         for (transformation_type in c("epi", "miss", "algor")) {
           openxlsx::write.xlsx(
             x = do.call(what = paste0("transformation_", transformation_type), args = list(df = df)), 
             file = sub(pattern = "Data", replacement = paste0(transformation_type, "_Results"), x = path_out)
           )
         }
       })
```

This works, if you have functions named after your transformations, ie if function `transformation_epi()` produces the epi-output etc.

Comment: Great, thank you. I tried file.list as well but I got stuck with the loop.

Comment: Tino, can I ask a funny question what \\d+\\ does? Sorry clearly I'm new to programing.

Comment: And also I actually have 3 different named results xlxs files for each folder. I don't want to merge them as they all contain different calculations. So can I use like path_out 1, path_out3 to save the new sets for each read data file?

Comment: `\\d+` tells it to match at least 1 digit. It's a regular expression. `\\.` matches the dot because you have to escape it, since `.` will match any character in regex. Hence it lists all files that follow the pattern: start with "Data_", followed by at least one digit, followed by ".xlsx".

Comment: Easiest would be to put all your transformations in one function, then call this function for each file, thus `some_transformations_to_your_data()` is a placeholder for your function or transformation (not necessarily a function but would be nice). Regarding the different outputs: write as many different files as you need, just use several `df_out` and `path_out`. Regarding this extension: edit the question and make proper example, especially indicate desired output.

Comment: Hi Tino, I did put all the transformations in to the function and ideally I would want to just call that for any folders with data sets but as I had a 3 out put excel file I got confused how to make sure they have the same extension number. So though ok I will read data sets in loop  and then inside that I will place my function.

Comment: But I got stuck with how to relate results from that function with the input file number.

Comment: I will have a proper try with all options and maybe I can figure out best solution for me.

Comment: input file Data203001 : output file would look like epi _Results_203001, miss_Results_203001, algor_Results203001.

Comment: Added another example. But please, as your question changes/becomes more complicated, for the sake of others who might benefit from it, add these aspects to your original question above and maybe explain a bit more or even give sample data, explain the structure of your directory and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list with the files that have `xlsx` extension

```
setwd(".../folder_with_excel")  
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx')
```

Then you can create a function `loc` that reads over the files. You can determine what sheet you want to read ("A" in this case) and the columns that you want to select. Also, create a variable that identifies the file that you are importing.

```
    loc = lapply(file.list, function(i){
      x = read_xlsx(i, sheet= "A")

  # Get the columns
      x = x[, c("col1", "col2", "col3")]

 # Add a column to say which file they're from
      x$file = i

# Return data
      x
    })
```

It will return a list of data frames. You can merge them into a single data frame using `rbindlist`.

```
# Transform the list into a data frame 
        all_excel_df =  rbindlist(loc)
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use `paste0` function to paste together parts of names of files like this:

```
suffixes<-c("203001", "203002")

for (suff in suffixes){
  data<-read(paste0('Data_',suff,'.xlsx'))
  results<-function_doing_something(data)
  write(results, paste0('Results_',suff,'.xlsx'))
}
```

Sorry for clumsy "meta-code-like" structure of above but you did not provide any information of process converting "Data_" to "Results_"

However `for` loops are slow in R, so next step might be using `walk` form `purrr` package.

Comment: Thank you, what I do from data to results is some tidying up of the factor levels, replacing missing data and group them by,  sorting them out according to some specific levels. I also use different filters to fetch data I need out and then I run frequency tables on them and compare .

Comment: After all that I end up with 3 different named excel folders each contains at least 3 sheets and that is what I need to alter be able to quickly work on that folders. So that is when I got stuck when I used file.list option. I couldn't understand how to run loop with an option to save from 1 input file 3 outputs files with different names but still same number.

Comment: also I'm working on weekly report data so for each year I have 52 weeks more or less depending from what I got available. So that is the reason I don't want to loos the index number at the end of result files.

Comment: You may use several `function_doing_something`'s and several `write` calls in one loop.

Answer (score -1):

I would use `dir()` function for determining names of files in your folder/directory.

```
library(readxl) # reading
library(WriteXLS) # writing
for(i in dir("data_files_folder")){

  cat(i, "\n")

  d <- read_excel(path = paste0("data_files_folder/", i))

  # something done with it 

  WriteXLS(d, ExcelFileName = paste0("keep_files_here/", i)  )

}
```

Comment: Since you only want to read xlsx-files, you might want to use `list.files(pattern = "\\.xlsx$")` instead of `dir()`, which would give you all files and directories -- `read_excel` only takes xlsx.

Comment: If he keeps all files in one folder, which usually are the case, it's fine to use `dir()`. 
`read_excel` takes both **xls** and xlsx.

Comment: thanks, I tried read.xlsx2 I got really confused with how to index them correctly.

Comment: That's not the point. Using `dir` is not robust since it will fail whenever you have something else than just xlsx/xls in the directory. This won't happen with `list.files`, because only files are listed. And it becomes even more robust if you define the pattern. Feel free to use `pattern = "\\.(xlsx|xls)$"` to allow for both, xlsx and xls. But in this case, `dir` is a bad solution.

Comment: I understand, that it's possible to take both with the right pattern. 
Just showed the one possible way, as you pointed out probably it's not best. 
About `read_excel`, as I said, it can read both formats.
Have a nice day :)